# Filter listview populated from database doesn't display results for non latin characters

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a listview which displays database's records and a textWatcher to filter the displayed items. The problem is that this works fine for latin characters, but not for unicode. Unicode displayed fine though. 
Here is the related code:

```
etFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
         int count, int after) {
       }

       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
         int before, int count) {
        dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
       }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
      });

      dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
             public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                 return provider.fechDobjectsByName(constraint.toString());
             }
         });
```

I didn' t find any related question here. Does anybody knows how is done?
EDIT:
Sorry this was my mistake. Search with Unicode characters display the results, but is case sensitive. I just now realized this.
So, how can search and display the result no matter if letters are Capital or not?

```
public Cursor fechDobjectsByName(String inputText) throws SQLException {

      Cursor mCursor = null;
      if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
       mCursor = database.query(DbHelper.TABLE_SONGS, 
         new String[] {DbHelper.COLUMN_ID,
         DbHelper.COLUMN_SONGNAME, DbHelper.COLUMN_SONGARTIST, 
         DbHelper.COLUMN_SONGGENRE}, 
         null, null, null, null, null);

      }
      else {
       mCursor = database.query(true, DbHelper.TABLE_SONGS, 
         new String[] {DbHelper.COLUMN_ID,
         DbHelper.COLUMN_SONGNAME, DbHelper.COLUMN_SONGARTIST, 
         DbHelper.COLUMN_SONGGENRE}, 
         DbHelper.COLUMN_SONGNAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
         null, null, null, null);
      }
      if (mCursor != null) {
       mCursor.moveToFirst();
      }
      return mCursor;
```

Comment: "how to search no matter if letters are Capital or not?" -- that would depend entirely on the implementation of `fechDobjectsByName()`, not presently shown in your question.

Comment: Yes, I suspected this. I'm adding the method now

Comment: After more testing, seems that case sensitive are only the unicode characters. If I search for a name with latin characters doesn't matter if is Capital or not, but for unicode does.